# How to install Zendframework 1 in xampp

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp

So i'm new in zendframework and i want to try zf version 1 , i cannot find a good documentation for this. i'm having an error when i try to run the downloaded file in xampp

here's the screen shot of my folder structure

[image]

I install zend framework using **composer zendframework/zenframework**

then here's the error

Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\public\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\library;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\public\index.php on line 17

Comment: Add `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'`; to `index.php`.

Comment: still same error

Comment: Add the `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` as localheinz said, and remove the `require_once 'Zend/Application.php';`

Answer (score 2):

you should read and understand step-by-step from here :

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Or,

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html

first try to understand the application structure.

As you are new in Zend framework, I think this is the best place to start.